# Can we cite Hatha Yoga Pradipika for Nath Sampraday related questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can we cite [Hatha Yoga Pradipika](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/index.htm) for [Nath Sampraday](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nath) related questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we can cite [Hatha Yoga Pradipika,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika) for Nath Sampradaya related questions.

It is because it was authored by [Swatmarama,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sv%C4%81tm%C4%81r%C4%81ma) the disciple of [Gorakhnath.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorakshanath) Swatamarama learned the secrets of Hatha Yoga from Gorakhnath and [Matseyndranath](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsyendranath) and wrote this book. As it is direct knowledge from Gorakhnath and Matseyndranath written by SwatmaRama, So, followers of **Natha Sampradaya** consider this as authentic text.

It is illustrated in Hatha Yoga Pradipika itself. The 4th verse of the book states:

> हठविद्या हि मत्स्येन्द्र गोरक्षाद्या विजानते ।
>   स्वात्मारामोऽथवा योगी जानीते ततप्रसादत ।। 
>  
>   Matsyendra, Goraksa, etc., knew Hatha Vidyâ, and by 
>   their favour Yogî Swâtmârâma also learnt it from them.

Verse 3 illustrates why Hatha Yoga Pradipika was written ?

> भ्रान्त्या बहुमतध्वान्ते राजयोगमजानतम् । 
>   हठप्रदीपिका धत्ते स्वात्मारामः कृपाकर ।। 
>  
>   Owing to the darkness arising from the multiplicity of 
>   opinions people are unable to know the Râja Yoga. 
>   **Compassionate Swâtmârâma composes the Hatha Yoga Pradipikâ like a torch to dispel it.**